# Voter registration total in California by party?

Tags: united-states, california, voter-registration

I am wondering what the total voter registration is in California. I want to know because I am curious about what it is and what it was. I would like to know what the trend in registration was over time. I want to know if there is a place where it is updated daily.

There is a website for a particular county in this state. It is at https://ocvote.com .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The California Secretary of State publishes [detailed voter registration data](https://www.sos.ca.gov/elections/voter-registration/voter-registration-statistics/). While it's not updated daily (I haven't seen any such data), it's still possible to draw trends in voter registration.